# NSMutableAttributedString's attribute NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName doesn't work correctly in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, nsattributedstring, strikethrough, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a mutable attributed string without NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName attribute like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"aaaa" attributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]}];
```

and another mutable attributed string with NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName attribute like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"bbbb"];
```

and a whole string containing two strings above:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *labelString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[labelString appendAttributedString:str1];
[labelString appendAttributedString:str2];
```

when I attach the whole string to a UILabel:

```
_label.attributedText = labelString;
```

It both display well in iOS7 and iOS8, like this:

<del>aaaa</del>bbbb

But when I exchange their positions:

```
[labelString appendAttributedString:str2];
[labelString appendAttributedString:str1];
```

It display correctly in iOS7 but not correctly in iOS8

ios7:  bbbb<del>aaaa</del>          ios8: bbbbaaaa

It seems that in iOS8, UILabel doesn't render the strikethrough correctly if the first character in the attributed string is not strikethroughed.
I think this is a bug in iOS8, is there anyone who encounter the same problem with me?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem.  Have you raised a radar?

Comment: FYI I have just added radar #18409995.

Comment: I've also added an open radar now: http://openradar.appspot.com/18409995 (been raising so many IOS8 thought I may as well learn how open radar works)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"bbbb" attributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleNone]}];
```

it should help

Comment: This also magically fixed my problem. I was attempting to highlight part of an attributed string by setting the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` with a color and an `NSRange`. The code worked perfectly on iOS 7, but I found that in iOS 8 the highlighting only worked if the range had a location of 0; any other value and it wasn't drawn. Creating the attributed string with your code fixed my problem somehow.

Answer (score 8):

On **iOS8.1.1** we have more problems with setting *NSMutableAttributedString*, like with *NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName*.

If your attributes are not changing try this and it will be.

I started reasoning by the UILabel that is spirit to chaneger attributes, so if we assume that the NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName not initialized the label text so we will need the initialize it .

What I do is initializing mutableAttributedString by a none NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName and change this attribute to highlight:
result is:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: myString attributes: @ {NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @ (NSUnderlineStyleNone)}];
             [string addAttributes: @ {NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @ (NSUnderlineStyleSingle)} range: [myString rangeOfString: mySubString]];
[MyLabel setAttributedText: string];
```

effective result <= iOS8.1.1

Comment: It works when MyLabel.numberOfLines is NOT 1. I tested it in iOS 8.1 simulator.

Answer (score 3):

Fix for the bug in iOS8: Strike Through first letter of the string with clear color and then Strike through the text in which ever range you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you are not starting the index from 0, try this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
[attributedStr addAttributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)} range:NSMakeRange(1, str.length)];
[attributedStr addAttributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)} range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName`, you should also add `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName`, which is set to 0. And in swift, you should use the rawValue of `NSUnderlineStyl`e.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue and changing NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName's value to NSUnderlineStyleNone doesn't fix it. Sure seems like iOS 8 bug.

Comment: Don't change the value to NSUnderlineStyleNone. Just add a NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName attribute with value NSUnderlineStyleNone to those text which is not strikethroughed.