# How to underline part of string with NSAttributedString objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

Underling a string only works when the range starts from zero. If i start it at 1 then it works. The green colour works regardless.

```
+ (NSAttributedString*)returnNSAttributedString:(NSString*)string range:(NSRange)range WithColour:(UIColor*)colour WithUnderLine:(BOOL)underline {
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
    if (underline) {
        [attributedString addAttributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)} range:range];
    }
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:colour range:range];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSRangeFromString(string)];
    return attributedString;
}
```

it works on iOS 7 not iOS 8.

Comment: It may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956183/nsmutableattributedstrings-attribute-nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-doesnt

Answer (score 10):

You can use the NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName and NSUnderlineColorAttributeName attributes. You can use it like this:

```
NSRange foundRange = [wordString rangeOfString:@"Base Mix"];
if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    [wordString beginEditing];
    [wordString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] range:foundRange];
    [wordString addAttribute:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName value:[NSColor redColor] range:foundRange];
    [wordString endEditing];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift:**

A little method. Gets a string and returns a NSMutableAttributedString with underline attribute over the full string-length.

```
func getUnderlinedAttributedString(string string: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString
{
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: string)
    let stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)

    attributedString.beginEditing()
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: stringRange)
    attributedString.endEditing()

    return attributedString
}
```