# How to underline a SKLabelNode in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can i underline a SKLabelNode in swift 4?

I have searched a lot, but it look like there is no option to do that..

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let mylabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"ChalkboardSE-Regular")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        mylabel.text = "Hello World"
        mylabel.position = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 , y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
        addChild(mylabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: At this moment I don't believe it's possible to underline a SKLabelNode. A workaround would be to make the label in an imageeditor ex. Photoshop, and then implement it in your game as a SKSpriteNode.

Comment: I do not have time to write an answer, but you should be able to use NSAttributedString to get the underline effect needed on an SKLabelNode

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423467/how-to-underline-part-of-string-with-nsattributedstring-objective-c

Comment: Thanks KnightOfDragon, with your link i make it work.. but only in iOS 11 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

With the link received from KnightOfDragon, i finally make it work.. (Thanks to KnightOfDragon for that!) but only in iOS 11 and newer. Is there another way to use it in iOS 9 and newer?

Here is the actual code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let mylabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"ChalkboardSE-Regular")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            mylabel.attributedText = getUnderlinedAttributedString(string: "Hello World")
        } else {
            mylabel.text = "Hello World"
        }
        mylabel.position = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 , y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
        addChild(mylabel)
    }


    func getUnderlinedAttributedString(string: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString
    {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: string)
        let stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)

        attributedString.beginEditing()
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: stringRange)
        attributedString.endEditing()

        return attributedString
    }
}
```

Comment: to be honest, I would not worry about supporting iOS 9 if you are doing sprite kit.  There are a lot of bugs in it, and I do not remember but I believe it is something like less than 10% of users are an older iOS